# Can my badges increase my reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, badges, post-ban

Can my badges increase my reputation? For example, could I use them to start a bounty?

Also, I was banned for editing and asking questions; can anyone give some suggestion about how to remove that ban?

Comment: You can also attend to little things like correct capitalization in your sentences.

Comment: how can remove the ban for asking question.?? i am stuck please help me

Comment: @Nirav: To start with, it appears you don’t have any undeleted questions, which suggests you have [some deleted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/3693828). Deleted posts weigh more heavily on post bans; the best route forward would be to see if there are any questions there that you could undelete and edit to improve.

Answer (score 4):

No, badges are separate from reputation. As such, you cannot use them to start bounties.

Post bans are not based on reputation, but rather on question score. As such, neither badges nor reputation will lift you out of one. If you have not already done so, you may want to read [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997)